# How can I validate that the headers of a CSV file match my struct?

Tags: csv, parsing, data-structures, struct, rust

I need to parse a CSV file, but before actually parsing, I need to check if the file header can be assigned to my needs.

The problem is that some fields may be missing or the order of the fields may be different for different files.

I have a struct for dish

```rust
struct Dish {
    title: String,
    ingredients: Vec<String>,
    spicy: Option<bool>,
    vegetarian: Option<bool>,
}
```

I need to generate an error for any CSV file with a header that has missing fields from the structure (not `Option`) or has extra fields:

```
title;spicy;vegeterian
```

```
title;ingredients;poisoned
```

Comment: To verify types you'll need to parse both the header line and a (trusted) data line.

Comment: https://docs.rs/csv/1.1.3/csv/index.html#example-with-serde

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`csv`](https://crates.io/crates/csv) crate has support for `serde`. The following example, adapted from [the docs](https://docs.rs/csv/1.1.3/csv/#example-with-serde) should do what you want:

```
use std::error::Error;
use std::io;
use std::process;

use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Dish {
    title: String,
    ingredients: Vec<String>,
    spicy: Option<bool>,
    vegetarian: Option<bool>,
}

fn example() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let mut rdr = csv::Reader::from_reader(io::stdin());
    for result in rdr.deserialize() {
        // Notice that we need to provide a type hint for automatic
        // deserialization.
        let dish: Dish = result?;
        println!("{:?}", dish);
    }
    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    if let Err(err) = example() {
        println!("error running example: {}", err);
        process::exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought I shouldn't iterate the reader if the csv header doesn't match, but double check this example and realized that the loop should return `Error` on the first iteration if the data doesn't match.